How can I color dot notation methods in the listings package?
I can't figure out a way to incorporate colored dot notation methods into my custom Python theme with the listings package of LaTeX.
For example, consider the following code:
1  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
2
3  def warn(*args, **kwargs):
4      pass
5  warnings.warn = warn
6  warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
7
8  print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

I would like the following characters to be colored in a particular color, although the preceding periods should NOT be colored:
Line 1: pyplot
Line 5: the first instance of warn (i.e. the one that's part of warnings.warn) but NOT the second instance of warn
Line 6: filterwarnings
Line 8: path and also join should BOTH be colored

Attempt 1:
I tried using a set of functions and moredelim statements to handle the three cases:

When the dot notation term is followed by a space (e.g. .pyplot above)
When the dot notation term is followed by parentheses (e.g. .filterwarnings above)
When the dot notation term is followed by another period (e.g. .path above)

The functions I used were like this:
\newcommand{\functionMethodSpaceHighlight}[1]{\textcolor{black{.}\textcolor{LstPythonMediumBlue}{#1}\ }
\newcommand{\functionMethodParHighlight}[1]{\textcolor{black}{.}\textcolor{LstPythonMediumBlue}{#1}(}
\newcommand{\functionMethodPeriodHighlight}[1]{\textcolor{black}{.}\textcolor{LstPythonMediumBlue}{#1}\textcolor{black{.}}

And the moredelim statements were like this:
moredelim = [is][\functionMethodSpaceHighlight]{.}{\ },
moredelim = [is][\functionMethodParHighlight]{.}{(},
moredelim = [is][\functionMethodParHighlight]{.}{.},

This produced weird results with extra periods, spaces, and '(' symbols added in the displayed code. I tried to fix this by trying different versions where the moredelim statements were instead like this:
moredelim = *[is][\functionMethodSpaceHighlight]{.}{\ },

Or like this:
moredelim = **[is][\functionMethodSpaceHighlight]{.}{\ },

But it never looked right.
My guess is that the problem with this attempt was due to the three moredelim statements all starting with the same character?

Attempt 2:
I tried including a period in my alsoletter statement:
alsoletter={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, .},

And then adding a morekeywords group for the terms individually:
morekeywords=[3]{.pyplot, .warn, .filterwarnings, .path, .join},
keywordstyle=[3]\color{LstPythonMediumBlue},

But this didn't find the terms, which I assume is because they were preceded by other letters (e.g. matplotlib for matplotlib.pyplot).

Attempts 3 and 4:
I tried the following two one-line suggestions from ChatGPT, which supposedly would color any letters and underscores that followed a period, but both attempts resulted in the error "Undefined control sequence":
moredelim=[is][\color{LstPythonMediumBlue}]{\.[a-zA-Z_]\w*}{},

moredelim=[is][\color{LstPythonMediumBlue}]{\.\w+}{},


If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every post, even in the original one. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78941124/2777074

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.
